# classpath loader error when app loads initially

Tags: codenameone, cloudinary

Good day all
I just discovered that my codename one app crashes on the simulator and android, without even loading the first page.
The following is the error i recieved:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javabc/SecureRandom
    at com.cloudinary.Cloudinary.(Cloudinary.java:113)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you installed the cloudinary cn1lib without installing the bouncy castle cn1lib. Did you install via the extension UI in Codename One settings?

Comment: Yes sir, I installed using the settings ui

Comment: Did you install bouncy castle too? Did you remove it after the install?